# DAX expression for Power BI measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, measure

[image]I am trying to create a measure in POWER BI, its to calculate the total revenue for a time period but it has a lot of conditions to it. i.e.

Total Revenue with following conditions
Shipping type = "Incoming"

Status  = Invoiced,Shipped,Received

if site = 29104 exclude product = S-ExtFreight,S-ProductInDelivery,S-WeighOnly

if site = 33103 exclude product = S-ExtFreight,S-WeighOnly

if site = 23103 exclude product = S-ExtFreight,SAxleWeigh

I tried to use the below expression but its not throwing me any values when I plot it on a graph.

Measure 2 = CALCULATE(
sum('Fact table'[Amount]),
'Fact table'[Site Code] = 29104 & 'Fact table'[Item Number] in {"S-ExtFreight","S-ProductInDelivery","S-WeighOnly"},
'Fact table'[Site Code] = 33103 & 'Fact table'[Item Number] in {"S-ExtFreight","S-WeighOnly"},
'Fact table'[Site Code] = 23103 & 'Fact table'[Item Number] in {"S-ExtFreight","S-AxleWeigh"})

Thanks Ashok for the update. I get this visual error once I bring it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `NOT([Column Name]) in` to exclude products. Also you need to use && for AND condition.

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE( sum('Fact table'[Amount]), 'Fact table'[Site Code] = 29104 && NOT('Fact table'[Item Number])  in {"S-ExtFreight","S-ProductInDelivery","S-WeighOnly"}, 'Fact table'[Site Code] = 33103 && NOT('Fact table'[Item Number]) in {"S-ExtFreight","S-WeighOnly"}, 'Fact table'[Site Code] = 23103 && NOT('Fact table'[Item Number]) in {"S-ExtFreight","S-AxleWeigh"})
```

Comment: Thanks Ashok, i applied this and it gives an error "The syntax for NOT is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Ashok, I have added an image that I get when I bring the measure for visualization

Comment: If it is solved accept answer and upvote

Comment: Done, what about the visual error, when I put in a table or a chart it gives me the error "calculation error in measure, DAX operations do not support comparing text with values of type integar. Consider using value or format function to convert one of the values"

Comment: change the format of site code to number using power query